# How to embed <pre> tag in a list in a wiki

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to embed a `<pre>` tag in within an ordered list, of the form:

```
# Some content
#: <pre>
Some pre-formatted content
</pre>
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone please let me know on how to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the better answer for continuing a numbered list after using the <pre> tag without resorting to html:

```
# one
#:<pre>
#:some stuff
#:some more stuff</pre>
# two
```

Produces:

1. one

```
   some stuff
   some more stuff
```

2. two

Comment: At least with the MediaWiki version currently used in Wikipedia, this does not work, and I would be pretty surprised if it worked anywhere else (`:` creates a `dl` tag, and there is no way to wrap some `dl`s but not the whole list into a `pre` tag).

Comment: 10 years later, this still doesn’t work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular HTML list:

```
<ol>
<li>Some Content</li>
<li><dl><dd><pre>Some pre-formatted content</pre></dd></dl></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I got from [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/85999) at Webmasters SE works for me:

```
# Some content
# <source>
Some pre-formatted content
</source>
# Some more content
```

Although the `<source>` tag is deprecated and modern markup should look like this:

```
# Some content
# <syntaxhighlight>
Some pre-formatted content
</syntaxhighlight>
# Some more content
```

---

If your pre content is code, you can use a language such as `<syntaxhighlight lang="php">` to get syntax highlighting.

Comment: In case someone want the "pre" style to be on its own without a number associated to is: ```# Some content
# <source>```.  The initial source tag just has to be on the same line as some content.

Comment: Note that `<source>` is a [deprecated](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight#Usage:~:text=still%20supported%2C%20but-,is%20deprecated,-.%20%E2%80%8E%3Csyntaxhighlight) tag.

Comment: Thanks @bfontaine, answer has been updated